# bash - i'm doing for i in *.mp4, then in the loop i want to use ${i} but without the .mp4. how can i do this?

Tags: command-line, bash

Basically i am doing this:

```
for i in *.mp4; 
do ffmpeg -i "${i}" -vf "movie=logo.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=10:10 [out]" -strict -2 -qscale 0 "${i}-watermarked.mp4"; 
done;
```

but this effectively does this command

```
do ffmpeg -i "video.mp4" -vf "movie=logo.png [watermark];\ 
 [in][watermark] overlay=10:10 [out]" -strict -2 -qscale 0 "video.mp4-watermarked.mp4";
```

the bit at the end - video.mp4-watermarked.mp4 is my issue. i want it to be video-watermarked.mp4.

how can i do this ?

Comment: I am to tired to write the answer, but you want to look at the `basename` command to strip the first mp4 extension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using bash try using `${i%%.mp4}`.

For your example that would be:

```
for i in *.mp4; 
do ffmpeg -i "${i}" -vf "movie=logo.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=10:10 [out]" -strict -2 -qscale 0 "${i%%.mp4}-watermarked.mp4"; 
done;
```

There are lots of other manipulations possible the term you might want to lookup in the manual pages is **Parameter Expansion**.